# Polymer ignores mouseclick after typing during 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have two inputs:

```
<input class="input" id="first" type="text" placeholder="this is first input">   
<input class="input" id="second" type="text" placeholder="this is second input">
```

If I type text in first input and after that I click outside the field - the click event not firing and the first field does not lose the focus. But if I wait for about 3 seconds after typing then the focus of the fields change normally. Also the click event works fine if I don't use Polymer's libs.

I use this library
chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/polymer/polymer-extracted.js

Any advice?

Regards,
Pavel

Comment: hi,could you showcase an example ? i guess you need to use on-blur for the same

Comment: sorry for confusing - seems to me that it is virtualbox issue, I can't reproduce it on real machine